# Back propagation for cross entropy loss function with softmax

Tags: gradient-descent, neural-networks

I am trying to solve the math for back propagation algorithm using cross-entropy cost/loss function and softmax activation function in output layer.

The network architecture for 3-class classification is as follows:

The input layer has two input neurons (i1 and i2)

There is a single hidden layer having 3 neurons (h1, h2 and h3)

The output layer has 3 output neurons (o1, o2 and o3). These output scores or logits are fed into the softmax function which then outputs the probabilities (S1, S2 and S3).

I am attaching a hand sketched image for a visual representation of the neural network.

[image]

w1 is the weight from hidden neuron h1 to output neuron o1.

And, w13 is the weight from input neuron i1 to hidden neuron h1.

The mathematical partial derivative equations which I have come up with are:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_1} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial S_1} * \frac{\partial S_1}{\partial out_{o1}} * \frac{\partial out_{o1}}{\partial net_{o1}} * \frac{\partial net_{o1}}{\partial w_1}$

OR:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_1} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial out_{01}} * \frac{\partial out_{o1}}{\partial net_{o1}} * \frac{\partial net_{o1}}{\partial w_1}$

Where, $S_1$ refers to softmax output for 1st class, $out_{o1}$ refers to output of first output neuron and $net_{01}$ refers to network input for output neuron $o1$.

Is my mathematical partial derivative equations correct?

Also, I wish to compute the partial derivative of:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{13}}$

What should the equations look like?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't mention what `net` and `out` are.

Comment: "net" is network input function for a neuron, while "out" is output of a neuron AFTER activation function is applied to "net". So, out = activation_function(net)

Comment: The way this is drawn, it almost looks like you have two hidden layers, not one, with $ o_1, o_2, o_3$ making up a 2nd hidden layer.

Comment: @MattCremeens I have updated the image